# How to construct colour from byte array?

Tags: java, android

Im struggling with very simple task (well, i think so). 
I have `byte[4]` array that represents colour values like `byte[0] = alpha`, 
`byte [1] = red` and so on. 
How can I convert this byte array to an actual colour object?
Thanks for an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bytes in Java are signed so the positive part can only hold values until 127, RGB goes up to 255. So you have to compensate for that:

```
byte b = (byte) 130;
int i = b & 0xFF;
System.out.println(i); //Prints 130 again
```

The int can then be passed to the Color constructor.

Edit: complete example:

```
byte[] values = new byte[] {(byte) 130, (byte) 150, (byte) 200, (byte) 200};
Color color = Color.argb(values[0] & 0xFF, values[1] & 0xFF, values[2] & 0xFF, values[3] & 0xFF);
System.out.println(color + " alpha " + color.getAlpha());
```

Comment: Starting with Java7, you want this:

    `new Color.argb(values[1] & 0xFF, values[2] & 0xFF, values[3] & 0xFF, values[0] & 0xFF);`